# Why is the past perfect used in the parts "had made" and "had grown"?

Tags: past-tense, perfect-aspect

> Pocho had made the decision to live near the human who had saved his life, so he soon became a member of the Snedden family. By now, Chito remarried, and together they had a daughter. Both, fortunately, loved the croc.
>
> Pocho had grown to 16 feet (5 meters), and weighed over 1,000 pounds (454 kg)

Source:
[Incredible story of a man and 1000-pound crocodile, they lived together for 20 years](https://web.archive.org/web/20170707193558/http://www.ntd.tv/inspiring/life/incredible-story-man-crocodile-twenty-year-friendship.html)

Why is the past perfect used in the parts "had made" and "had grown"?

Answer (score 1):

As in most cases, the past perfect is used to indicate that

> Pocho had made the decision

before he started living with the Snedden family.
Likewise:

> Pocho had grown to 16 feet

before he weighed over 1,000 pounds (as the growing happened before achieving the considerable weight)